# How to avoid duplicate entries when saving in database in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a button but it can save duplicate entries i don't know how to correctly put a if not exist operator pls help..

```
  cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Students(Familyname,Firstname,Middlename,StudentID)VALUES('" & txtname.Text & "','" & txtfname.Text & "','" & txtmname.Text & "','" & txtid.Text & "')", cn)

    cn.Open()
    i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    cn.Close()

    If txtname.Text <> "" Then
    ElseIf i > 0 Then
        MsgBox("Save Sucessfully!", MessageBoxIcon.Information, "Success")
        showrecord()
        clear()
    Else
        MsgBox("Save Failed!", MessageBoxIcon.Error, "Error")
    End If
```

Comment: What is your primary key?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i

Comment: @  Colour Dalnet - id is my primary key

Comment: StudentID is unique right?

Comment: What constitutes a duplicate? Determine that and add a unique index on it so the database won't allow it. Then have a prior database call that looks for that already existing and let the user know if they are trying to insert a duplicate.

Comment: It is the job of the database to provide Unique OK, so you ought not be INSERTing StudentID.  Before you add a record check if one exists with the existing Names(s) depending on what you define as unique (just use a COUNT query).  And **always** use SQL parameters for many reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one :

```
cn.Open()
Dim intReturn as integer
Dim strSql as string = "Select * from Students where StudentID = @StudentID"

sqlcmd = new sqlcommand(strSql, cn)
With sqlcmd.parameters
  .addwithvalue("@StudentID", ctype(txtid.text,string)
End with

intReturn = sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar

If(intReturn > 0)
    cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Students(Familyname,Firstname,Middlename,StudentID)VALUES('" & txtname.Text & "','" & txtfname.Text & "','" & txtmname.Text & "','" & txtid.Text & "')", cn)

    i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery

    If txtname.Text <> "" Then
    ElseIf i > 0 Then
        MsgBox("Save Sucessfully!", MessageBoxIcon.Information, "Success")
        showrecord()
        clear()
    Else
        MsgBox("Save Failed!", MessageBoxIcon.Error, "Error")
    End If
Else
    MsgBox("Student Already Exist", MessageBoxIcon.Error, "Error")
End If
cn.Close()
```

And don't forget to make your StudentID field as Unique in your database.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to prevent duplicate insert:

```
Dim sql = "INSERT INTO Students(Familyname, Firstname, Middlename, StudentID) " & _
            "VALUES(@FamilyName, @Firstname, @Middlename, @StudentID)" & _
            "WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Students WHERE StudentId = @StudentID)"

        Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string here")
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, cn)

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FamilyName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtname.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Firstname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtfname.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Middlename", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtmname.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudentID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtid.Text

            Dim i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        End Using
```

*You should always use parameterized queries to avoid SQL Injection attacks.*

**NOTE:** Please apply appropriate field types.